# Why FIQ and IRQ need to disable in Start up code

Tags: u-boot

In the U-boot start up code (arch/arm/cpu/armv7/start.S), FIQ and IRQs are disabled using CPSR(current program status register).

Can you please tell me why we have to disable these interrupts in the startup code?

Answer (score 0):

I would say for safety. U-boot may not be the first loader in the system, and if the loader is chained from another loaded, it may have already enabled interrupt sources that may occur. Disabling interrupts ensures that U-boot initialization phase is not altered by any unwanted interrupt.